# bootstrap footer iPad mini 2021

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have the following footer menu in my application:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right bg-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

This works fine, but on an iDevice like my iPad Mini 2021 the "home bar" (the line at the bottom of the device) overlaps the menu. I'm assuming this is also the case on iPhone without home button. Is it possible to give the menu some padding/margin at the bottom (on devices without home button only) to prevent this?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<body class="bg-danger">
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right bg-light mb-3 mb-md-3 mb-lg-0 <==[if u want margin on icon]" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mb-3 mb-md-0 mb-lg-0 <==[use it if u want magin on list items] " id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: That will add margin on all devices instead of just devices with the home bar at the button.

Comment: then add responsive class or use pure css @media querie

Comment: Of course I thought of that, but that will effect both devices with and without home button, so that won't work.

Comment: can u plz specify me what y want ?? i don't get it yet what u want.

Comment: bro for list margin bottom u can use on ul class  mb-3 mb-lg-0. u have to define small screen as well as md and learge screen also